# C++ optional<> and delayed construction of noncopyable object

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, noncopyable, boost-optional

See the below code,

The question is: how can I delay the construction of an object that is non-copyable, using optional<>.

I'm using boost::optional in the example, although I believe its now in the std::optional standard too.

Yes, I could use scoped_ptr<>, however I wanted to allocate on the stack, not the heap.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct HardFoo : noncopyable { };

int main()
{
   optional<HardFoo> ok_1( in_place() ); // OK
   // optional<HardFoo> no_1( HardFoo() );  // won't compile

   optional<HardFoo> delay_construct;
   // delay_construct = HardFoo(); // won't compile
   // delay_construct = optional<HardFoo>( in_place() ); // won't compile
   // delay_construct.swap( optional<HardFoo>( in_place() ) ); // won't compile

   return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++, I assume it wouldn't matter whether its C++03 or C++11 in this case, as its a fundamental design issue rather than just a stuff up in the code.

As requested, some error messages, for this one, I uncommented:

```
delay_construct = HardFoo();

$ g++ -g -Wall -o test -I/stuff/boost/ test.cpp
In file included from /stuff/boost/utility.hpp:18:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::assign_value(boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type, boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::is_not_reference_tag) [with T = HardFoo; boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type = const HardFoo&; boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::is_not_reference_tag = mpl_::bool_<false>]’:
/stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:307:12:   required from ‘void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::assign(boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type) [with T = HardFoo; boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type = const HardFoo&]’
/stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:606:9:   required from ‘boost::optional<T>& boost::optional<T>::operator=(boost::optional<T>::argument_type) [with T = HardFoo; boost::optional<T> = boost::optional<HardFoo>; boost::optional<T>::argument_type = const HardFoo&]’
test.cpp:14:30:   required from here
/stuff/boost/noncopyable.hpp:28:26: error: ‘const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable& boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::operator=(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
test.cpp:6:8: error: within this context
In file included from /stuff/boost/optional.hpp:15:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:433:69: note: synthesized method ‘HardFoo& HardFoo::operator=(const HardFoo&)’ first required here 
In file included from /stuff/boost/utility.hpp:18:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct(boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type) [with T = HardFoo; boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type = const HardFoo&]’:
/stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:308:12:   required from ‘void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::assign(boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type) [with T = HardFoo; boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type = const HardFoo&]’
/stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:606:9:   required from ‘boost::optional<T>& boost::optional<T>::operator=(boost::optional<T>::argument_type) [with T = HardFoo; boost::optional<T> = boost::optional<HardFoo>; boost::optional<T>::argument_type = const HardFoo&]’
test.cpp:14:30:   required from here
/stuff/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27:7: error: ‘boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
test.cpp:6:8: error: within this context
In file included from /stuff/boost/optional.hpp:15:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:346:8: note: synthesized method ‘HardFoo::HardFoo(const HardFoo&)’ first required here
```

There is an answer suggesting to use in_place directly,
it works with this:

```
   optional<HardFoo> ok( in_place() );
```

but not this:

```
   optional<HardFoo> no( in_place<HardFoo>() ); // BAD
```

The error messages:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall -o test -I/stuff/boost/ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:15:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘in_place()’
test.cpp:15:44: note: candidates are:
In file included from /stuff/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52:0,
                 from /stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:24,
                 from /stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:37,
                 from /stuff/boost/optional.hpp:15,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:73:1: note: template<class A0> boost::in_place_factory1<A0> boost::in_place(const A0&)
/stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:73:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:15:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from /stuff/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:57:0,
                 from /stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:24,
                 from /stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:37,
                 from /stuff/boost/optional.hpp:15,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:73:1: note: template<class A0, class A1> boost::in_place_factory2<A0, A1> boost::in_place(const A0&, const A1&)
/stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:73:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:15:44: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
In file included from /stuff/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:62:0,
                 from /stuff/boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp:24,
                 from /stuff/boost/optional/optional.hpp:37,
                 from /stuff/boost/optional.hpp:15,
                 from test.cpp:1:
```

Comment: When you say *won't compile* you should tell us what the compiler message is. Also, whether you are using C++03 or C++11 the easiest solution may differ.

Comment: The reason it doesn't compile, is because it would be a copy-construction.  And the class is noncopyable.

Comment: It depends on the version of your compiler and the options you are using, in C++11 the class could be *move-constructible* and a number of examples should compile then (depending on whether `boost::noncopyable` has been updated to provide move constructors/assignment operator).

Comment: I see, well I'll be on C++03 for a few more months until I can also move from MSVC-2010 to MSVC-2012 (my other compiler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to in_place directly into the object:

```
delay_construct = boost::in_place<Type>(params);
```

Note that it appears that boost didn't support default construction through factories (nullary factories) until 1.35.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't compile for me when I add in: optional<HardFoo> no( in_place<HardFoo>() ); // BAD

Comment: I'll mark this is answered, but if you could help me with the compile error (above), that would be appreciated :)

Comment: @elegant dice You didn't happen to be running boost-1.34 or earlier do you? Older boost didn't seem to support such a thing directly.

Comment: I'm on boost 1.53, g++ 4.7.2.

Comment: It works fine if I use in_place() ie without specifying the <HardFoo>.  Perhaps I need to #include something specific for typed in_place ?

Answer (score 3):

In C++14, we will have `std::optional`, which happens to have `std::optional::emplace`. So you can do:

```
std::optional<HardFoo> delay_construct;
delay_construct.emplace(constructor_arg_1, constructor_arg_2);
```

Comment: Nice, I like the sound of that!  Why doesn't boost have that yet?